# how to git and gitlab mirroring

Tags: git, gitlab

i'm new in git and gitlab.
i have a fresh gitlab setup on a server, an a git repo on another server.

1- create a new project on gitlab

2- then use:

```
git remote add origin git@192.168.2.70:pbx/mahnapbx.git
git push -u origin master
```

for remote existing repo to my new gitlab project.

now i can clone my gitlab repo in my IDE(netbeans) and add/edit some files and commit/push to my gitlab project then i can see all of my files/commit in gitlab

but the problem is my existing reop do not update... i can't see my new files or edits in the existing Repo.

what can i do for solving ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the changes to the other repository, too.

Add another repository:

```
git remote add other otherip/otherrepo
```

then push to that one

```
git push other master
```

Comment: already i have two Repo fist my existing and second one that Gitlab created automatically...
i do that's commands on my existing Repo

Comment: Yeah, I understood the following: you say you have two repos and in one, you don't see the changes. So you need to push to both repositories.

Comment: when i push on my IDE... the changes are visible in gitlab... but in visible in the old existing Repo.
i want to when i push to the gitlab repo, the existing repo on anther server will be updated...

Comment: Yes, you need to push to origin and the other repositories, or set up a script that does that.